# Пунктуация при обращениях в стихотворении «Славянам» Ф. Тютчева

Tags: пунктуация

> Привет вам задушевный, **братья,
>
>   Со всех Славянщины концов**,
>   Привет наш всем вам, без изъятья!
>   Для всех семейный пир готов!
>   Недаром вас звала Россия
>   На праздник мира и любви;
>   Но знайте, гости дорогие,
>   Вы здесь не гости, вы — свои!

Допустим, человек не знаком со стихотворением Ф. Тютчева. Он должен расставить знаки препинания в первых двух строках. Почему в таком случае нельзя рассматривать слова «братья со всех Славянщины концов» как распространенное обращение и, соответственно, не ставить вторую запятую?

Comment: А в ответах как раставлены запятые?

Comment: @Серж как в цитате.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если задание состоит в том, чтобы расставить запятые, то ответ возможен только один: "братья со всех Славянщины концов" — распространённое обращение. Внимательно прочитав стихотворение, любой поймет, что автор (от имени России) обращается ко "всем вам", славянам "со всех Славянщины концов", и всех "звала Россия на праздник мира и любви".

А что получается, если считать, что только "братья" - обращение? Обращаясь к неким неназванным братьям, автор посылает им привет "со всех Славянщины концов". Что это за отдельная группа "братьев", которую все славяне приветствуют, Россия зовет в гости и т. п.? Все поставлено с ног на голову.

Comment: А почему ж нельзя к группе - делегатам съезда- от имени всех славян? Это и есть обращение к делегатам, а не ко всем славянам, это их, избранников, звала Россия, чтобы они передали всем, что для России  они "свои".

Comment: По-моему, это выбор автора. Кстати, там были делегаты не только из Славянщины, но и из Западной Европы, только поляков не было, им бойкот объявлен. Тютчев был одержим идеей духовного воссоединения всех славян. Не стоит замудряться над этим, в настоящих тестах на ЕГЭ таких некорректных заданий не будет. Сенина просто не могла подумать, что так глубоко будут копать, в основном все дети видят обращение БРАТЬЯ.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя рассматривать эти слова как распространённое обращение потому, что Тютчев их так не рассматривал, если эта пунктуация соответствует рукописному оригиналу.
А в предложенной Вами ситуации, полагаю, отсутствие запятой нельзя рассматривать как ошибку, потому что незнающему человеку будет действительно проблематично определить, где заканчивается обращение. Поэтому нужно либо оставить обособление обращения, либо объяснить этот момент непосредственно при выполнении задания.

Comment: Самое интересно, что это из ЕГЭ. И вот, как его правильно выполнить, одному богу известно.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Это некорректный вопрос для ЕГЭ, где нужно выбрать конкретный вариант ответа.

Comment: А то, что имел в виду Тютчев, описано в каких-нибудь источниках?

Comment: К сожалению, я не литературовед, не могу помочь Вам в этом вопросе.

Comment: Могу только посоветовать попробовать поискать наиболее старые издания (быть может, где-то есть сканы или Вы живёте в крупном городе с хорошей библиотекой), изданные ближе к XIX веку, или поискать анализ в какой-то научной литературе. Хотя не знаю, стоит ли так мучиться из-за задания ЕГЭ.

Comment: Мучиться не стоит, конечно. Стоит сменить сборник заданий как можно скорее :)

Comment: Не думаю, в других  нахожу  гораздо грубее ошибки, уже несколько заданий с двумя ответами видела. Надо писать в министерство, не молчать, учёные эти деньги делают, безалаберно стали относиться к выпуску методических материалов, но Сенина мне нравится.

Comment: @Людмила вы случаем не слышали, ФИПИ в этом году без опечаток?

Comment: Не знаю, у Егораевой не видела опечаток и есть новое 20 задание

Answer (score 2):

> Допустим, человек не знаком со стихотворением Ф. Тютчева. Он должен расставить знаки препинания в первых двух строках. Почему в таком случае нельзя рассматривать слова «братья со всех Славянщины концов» как распространенное обращение и, соответственно, не ставить вторую запятую?

Почему же нельзя? Можно.

В ряде изданий Тютчева эта запятая и не ставится.

P.S.

К сожалению, не могу более подробно. Еду в метро, пишу с айпада.

ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ

Немного подробнее…

Стихотворение это было написано Тютчевым в связи со Славянским съездом, проходившим с 8 по 15 мая в Петербурге, а с 16 по 27 мая в Москве. Оно было прочитано (Б. М. Маркевичем?) как приветствие гостям на банкете в Петербургском Дворянском собрании 11 мая 1867 г., в день церковного празднования памяти славянских первоучителей и просветителей святых равноапостольных Кирилла и Мефодия.

Автограф неизвестен.

Первая публикация — сб. "Братьям-славянам". М. 1867, май.

В этой публикации запятая после слова *братья* присутствовала:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохранялась она и в последующих изданиях Тютчева, в т. ч. и в изданном в 1987 г. полном собрании его сочинений (Библиотека поэта. Большая серия. Изд. третье).

В вышедшем в начале двухтысячных годов первом научном издании сочинений Тютчева («Полное собрание сочинений и письма» Федора Ивановича Тютчева (1803–1873) в шести томах) пунктуация в разбираемом стихотворении была изменена — запятая перед находящимся в постпозиции к слову *братья*   **несогласованным определением**  *со всех Славянщины концов*  была убрана.

Так же (без запятой)  впоследствии было напечатано это стихотворение и в сборнике "Россия и Запад" (М., 2007)...

Comment: Это опять из ЕГЭ. Интересно, можно ли считать это задание корректным с одним вариантом ответа? Я был бы благодарен, если бы вы привели те издания, в которых запятой нет.

Comment: 1. http://www.fedor-tutchev.ru/poezia334.html 2. http://www.stihi-xix-xx-vekov.ru/tutchev283.html

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова спасибо! Может, тогда и в бумажных есть? (Ну, уже очевидно, что задание не корректно. Ужасный сборник вышел у Сениной...)

Comment: _Может, тогда и в бумажных есть?_ === Есть. Причем,  в наиболее авторитетном, на мой взгляд, издании -- шеститомном собрании сочинений, вышедшем в 2002 году. Буду сегодня в Ленинке, могу, если хотите, сфотографировать.

Comment: @slava1947 я верю! Тогда, безусловно, ошибка авторов сборника.

Comment: @slava1947, Информация очень ценная и интересная, однако вопросы остаются: откуда (от кого) привет и кому? Повторюсь, мне кажется логичной только одна версия: автор (от имени хозяев праздника) приветствует братьев, приехавших со всех Славянщины концов: "Привет вам задушевный, братья со всех Славянщины концов!"

Comment: _М_Г: мне кажется логичной только одна версия: автор (от имени хозяев праздника) приветствует братьев, приехавших со всех Славянщины концов._ === Ну конечно так! Но противоречила ли такому пониманию  и Правилам поставленная после _братьев_ запятая? Затрудняла, приводила к двоякости понимания -- это да, а вот противоречила ли... См. Правила-56: _§ 151. Запятыми выделяются <...> 6. Существительные в косвенных падежах с предлогами и, реже, без предлогов, **если им придается большая самостоятельность, чем обычно**_... А уж какие правила были во времена Тютчева...

Comment: _А уж какие правила были во времена Тютчева..._ Согласна с Вами (смотрите: ровно 150 лет прошло!). Даже в представленном отрывке есть "не даром" — раздельно... Я бы не стала ставить запятую, если бы мне пришлось сдавать ЕГЭ. (Слово ругательное какое-то...)